# How to count non-empty cells in a column only if the adjacent cells in previous 2 columns are empty?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, count, counting, countif

I am trying to achieve this in Google Sheets, but nothing is working out.

Here is the table [image: table]

In the column B, I want to count all non-0 cells. This is easy and I have done that.

In column C, I want to count all non-0 cells in column C, *only* if the cell to the left is empty. I have been able to do this too.

But now in column D, I want to count non-0 cells in column D, *if and only if* both the adjacent cells in column B and C are empty. I am not able to do this.

In cell D9 I should be getting a 1 - because only cell D8 has a value where B8 and C8 are empty.

How do I achieve this?

Excuse the Excel screenshot, but I want to achieve this in GoogleSheets.

Please note, I realise I can do this with if statements. However in the real dataset, I have 35 columns, so you can see where it gets cumbersome to use so many if statements.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you player0. That is some hardcore formula and it works! wow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in D9 try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(D4:D8, D4:D8<>"", C4:C8="", B4:B8="")))
```

Comment: That does work, however, I would have to enter those conditions for previous columns 34 times in my real data set. Any easier way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: @jqlifer1 can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TmyOozzSp60FEqYl2rtzoPOe29CChno9I52lx2WZBoU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @jqlifer1 not sure if I understand correctly... you want to have this count formula in every column (at the bottom) and every next one should include all previous columns? is that correct?

Comment: You are correct that I want the count formula at the bottom of every column.

However from the second column onwards, what I want the formula to do is count the non-empty (or non-zero) cells in the second column, only if the cell to its left (ie in column 1) is empty.

So your initial solution works. But if I wanted that formula for columns E through to AC, I don't want to keep entering the conditions in the formula.

Comment: @jqlifer1 see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pCeoUr_Y-CMItxbXaa1QI6apygLHoiBBHrgkJ8zLb10/edit#gid=0